# flutter doctor --android-licenses Error: Could not find or load main class Studio

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I've already tried reinstalling Android Studio, AndroidSDK, all the tools for the SDK, Flutter, and configuring the Environment Variables.

I've also tried using `sdkmanger -licenses` but it still comes with the same error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsg2c.png)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: do yo have android studio installed?

Comment: Yes I do have it installed. I even tried to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correct following is what worked for me.

1. Execute command prompt as administrator.
2. Run the command flutter doctor --android-licenses and accept all licenses.
3. Run the command flutter doctor -v to check if the issue was solved.
4. To make sure that is everything is ok, execute the command prompt as a regular user (your user) and execute flutter doctor -v again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried doing the steps as you said but nothing's changed. It's still giving the same error.